# Две части реплики поясняются двумя авторскими фразами: пунктуационное оформление параллелизма конструкций

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Ситуация такая: имеется "двухчастная" прямая речь персонажа, к каждой части которой следует комментарий автора. Пример:

> После обеда Пётр сказал: "Завтра с утра я поеду на рыбалку..." — чем
> огорчил Анну, (—) "...но к вечеру буду и, как договаривались, пойдём в
> кино", — чем примирил Анну с рыбалкой.

Этот вариант мне кажется оптимальным, но не уверен в необходимости взятого в скобки тире.

Если оформлять предложение по правилам, то параллелизма не выйдет, так как первая авторская фраза будет в кавычках, а вторая за ними:

> После обеда Пётр сказал: "Завтра с утра я поеду на рыбалку, — чем
> огорчил Анну, — но к вечеру буду и, как договаривались, пойдём в
> кино", — чем примирил Анну с рыбалкой.

"Типичное не то", совершенно не отвечает моей задумке.

Есть ещё вариант:

> После обеда Пётр сказал: "Завтра с утра я поеду на рыбалку (чем
> огорчил Анну), но к вечеру буду и, как договаривались, пойдём в
> кино (чем примирил Анну с рыбалкой)".

Но в таком варианте, на мой взгляд, недостаточно чётко даётся понять, что фразы в скобках — авторские; выглядит как какое-то шизофреническое двухголосие Петра.

**Итак, ваши варианты, как решить пунктуационную задачку?** Уточню: требуется именно вариант с частями прямой речи "в подбор", не абазцирование.

Answer (score 0):

Мне не очень понятно применение **многоточия и тире** в подобных предложениях с **авторскими замечаниями**. Я бы лучше использовала один из вариантов со скобками, он кажется вполне ясным и оправданным:

(1) После обеда Пётр сказал:  «Завтра с утра я поеду на рыбалку (чем огорчил Анну).  Но к вечеру буду и, как договаривались, пойдём в кино (чем примирил Анну с рыбалкой)».

(2) После обеда Пётр сказал:  «Завтра с утра я поеду на рыбалку (чем огорчил Анну), но к вечеру буду и, как договаривались, пойдём в кино (чем примирил Анну с рыбалкой)».

В справочниках правила оформления таких замечаний мне не попадались, а из классики можно привести такой пример со скобками:

– *Да, да, я знаю вас, Базаров, – повторила она. (**За ней водилась привычка, свойственная многим провинциальным и московским дамам, – с первого дня знакомства звать мужчин по фамилии.**) – Хотите сигару?*

Но там реплика оформлена как распространенное предложение в скобках, а здесь короткое замечание. Так что не очень ясная тема, только по аналогии можно что-то выбрать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134048/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------).

Comment: @Sharon помнится, у нас тут была длинная дискуссия, но чат уже удалился. В любом случае, Вам, наверное, будет интересен ответ из ИРЯ РАН, полученный мной сегодня на этот вопрос (я его скопировал в гугл документы, чтобы можно было прислать ссылку): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PJwcDiEGjoiZWpbXcWzhxsutEDVO6EW3Rm_S0OPBIdU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Nektoid
Спасибо большое за информацию. Непонятным для меня осталось мнение о том, что при  использовании скобок сказанное принадлежит Петру (с чего бы это). Но, возможно, такое оформление просто запрещено, то есть вставку нельзя вставлять в прямую речь непосредственно. Формально это, вероятно, так, но по смыслу понятно, что это мнение автора.