# Выделение кавычками внутренней речи

Tags: пунктуация

И у Розенталя (§ 47), и у Лопатина (§ 139) указано, что внутреннюю речь следует выделять кавычками.

- > *(Розенталь)* Независимо от места, занимаемого по отношению к словам
  > автора, кавычками выделяется внутренняя речь — невысказанные мысли:
  > *Смотрю вслед ему и думаю: «Зачем живут такие люди?»* (М. Г.); *«Что-то в
  > ней есть жалкое всё-таки», — подумал я* (Ч.).
- > *(Лопатин)* Только кавычками выделяется внутренняя (подумал про себя)
  > речь в авторском тексте, вне диалога: *Кузьма посмотрел, куда указали.
  > Там, на склоне другого косогора, цепочкой шли косцы. За ними ровными
  > строчками оставалась скошенная трава — красиво. «Какая-то из них —
  > Марья», — спокойно подумал Кузьма* (Шукш.); *Кузьма с радостью смотрел
  > на нее. «Чего я, дурак, искал еще?» — думал он* (Шукш.).

Тем не менее я регулярнейшим образом встречаю в художественной литературе примеры с невыделением внутренней речи кавычками:

- > *(Стругацие)* Вредная бабка постелила мне на полу. Ну уж нет, подумал я, запер дверь
  > на щеколду, перетащил постель на диван и стал раздеваться. Сумрачный
  > свет падал из окна, на дубе шумно возился кот. Я замотал головой,
  > вытряхивая из волос мусор. Странный это был мусор, неожиданный:
  > крупная сухая рыбья чешуя. Колко спать будет, подумал я, повалился на
  > подушку и сразу заснул.
- > *(Пелевин)* Собственно, сама по себе она ни на кого не похожа, подумал
  > я, открывая дверь в квартиру, ведь, если я гляжу на неё и она кажется
  > мне по-своему совершенным произведением искусства, дело здесь не в
  > ней, а во мне, которому это кажется.
- > (Гранин) Хорошая тема, подумал я, в чем-то он прав, важная тема — как
  > изготавливаются подлецы, как вырастает ненависть. Он ненавидел Зубра
  > посмертно. Есть вечная любовь, до конца дней. Это была вечная
  > ненависть.
- > *(Искандер)* Чик попробовал ложку густейшего мацони. Это, подумал он,
  > вкуснее, чем сливки. Хотя Чик сливки никогда не ел, он полагал, что у
  > них вкус пенок.
- > *(Маканин)*: Стрепетов, может быть, и рад, но, скорее всего, растерян. Он
  > думает: а был ли тот разговор в машине, не померещилось ли, то есть не
  > сам разговор, а смысл и значение его – были ли? Или же это какая-то
  > психологическая накладка и самообман?.. Стрепетов спешно закуривает.

Таких примеров десятки, если не сотни.

В одной (очень хорошей) книге по литмастерству пишется:

> *(Л. Крон "Как увлечь читателя, используя когнитивную психологию)* ...как же выразить мысли героя в повествовании от второго или третьего
> лица? Читателю кажется, что вы используете что-то вроде телепатии.
> Хорошие истории так здорово это делают, что мы не замечаем механизма
> действия. Бьюсь об заклад, вы много раз читали книги, написанные от
> третьего лица, которые так ловко погружали вас в сознание героев, что,
> размышляя над тем, как они это делают, вы все еще задаетесь вопросом,
> нужно ли ставить мысли персонажей в кавычки или выделять их курсивом.
> Ответ – ни то ни другое. Ни курсива, ни кавычек. Никаких меток. Как
> только вы овладеете искусством незаметно вставлять в текст мысли
> героя, читатель автоматически начнет их отличать от голоса
> рассказчика.

**Получается, что русскоязычные авторы этот приём уже давным-давно используют, причём в повествовании и от первого лица тоже?  А что же справочники?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Розенталя этот материал излагается в **§ 50. Слова автора внутри прямой речи.** Пункт 1. Примечание 2 (3,4)

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158

**Не выделяется кавычками прямая речь** в следующих случаях:

(3) если в середину прямой речи вставлен глагол ***говорит***, играющий роль **вводного слова**, указывающего на источник сообщения: Умру, говорит, и слава Богу, говорит; не желаю, говорит, жить (Т.); Я, ***говорит***, самого вахмистра жандармерии из пистолета убить хочу (Верш.);

(4) если в середину предложения, представляющего собой сообщение из периодической печати, вставлено **указание на источник сообщения** (такая вставка выделяется запятыми): Речь оратора, ***продолжает корреспондент***, вызвала горячую поддержку у большинства присутствующих.

То же, если высказывание говорящего передается **приблизительно** (тем самым утрачивается характер прямой речи): Предлагаемый проект, ***указал докладчик***, получил уже апробацию на практике.

Comment: Это же совершенно другие случаи. Посмотрите примеры, которые я подобрал: там именно внутренняя речь, переданная а) дословно, б) с глаголом 'думать', не одиночным нигде, в) не из периодической печати. По Розенталю все мои случаи должны быть в кавычках  — сравните с его примерами из § 47.

Comment: А вам не все равно – сказал, подумал и т.д. Обобщить тему не можете? Ну давайте я вам помогу. Назовем ее так:  Слова автора, оформленные как вводные предложения. И что мне смотреть внимательно!  Весь Акунин (из того,что я у него читаю, так написан). И на форуме этот вопрос обсуждался, из других книг приводились примеры... Ну поищите что получше, может, найдете.

Comment: "В тоже время здесь возможно оформление по образцу БСП без кавычек" — здесь "в то же" раздельно. // Спасибо, я не знал, что это называется "несобственно-прямая речь". // Кстати, я вас прошу ответить и на прошлый мой вопрос: https://clck.ru/b2oeG, возможно, там тоже ситуация, к которой подходит что-то из справочника, а я не увидел. Но мне кажется, там случай, на который чёткого справочного решения нет.

Comment: Варианты бывают разные, автор выбирает то, что подходит для его ситуации, в том числе по интонации.  Я эту тему называю вариантами оформления прямой речи, кроме классического. И она у Розенталя по разным темам разбросана, что не очень удобно. Кстати у вас там вроде нет несобственно-прямой речи, это вообще особый случай, тоже довольно спорный. А ваше второе предложение я уже смотрела, у меня по нему вопросов больше чем ответов.  Хотела спросить, о каких правилах и в каких источниках  вы говорите и как называете эту тему.

Comment: *Хотела спросить, о каких правилах и в каких источниках вы говорите и как называете эту тему.* — не понял, относится это к этому вопросу или к тому. Если к тому, то лучше комментарий напишите там и с конкретикой, а то я простужен, у меня мозг нынче тяжко варит...

Comment: Мозги берегите, отдыхайте больше, а вы всё за работой. Я имела в виду https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470186/Две-части-реплики-поясняются-двумя-авторскими-фразами-пунктуационное-оформление

Comment: А. Там я говорил о правилах оформления прямой речи, т.е. Розенталь § 47 и далее.

Comment: Меня интересует такая тема: авторские замечания внутри предложения с прямой речью. Как они оформляются, есть ли для этого правила? Мне такие не встречались, а в текстах попадались только скобки.